# When will Gaming carry advertisements?

Tags: discussion, advertisements

Lets face it, advertisement is the life blood of the internet.  I want to see gaming succeed, and in many ways it has. Particularly it's the fourth most visited site on SE, with 15k visits a day.  So, when will Gaming start having ads?

---

Why do I care?  Two reasons.

- I want the site to pay for itself, and as such, secure its future.
- I'm tired of seeing the Area51 ads.

Comment: I'm just going to put an enigmatic "Hm......." here.

Comment: Is this something I'd have to turn off Adblock to notice?

Comment: @Brant Add `*.stackexchange.com` to your filterlist.  Help support the sites you love!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> So, when will Gaming start having ads?

We don't know, but probably not any time soon. I'd say no sooner than 12 months from now at the *earliest*.

> I'm tired of seeing the Area51 ads.

You're going to hurt Area 51's feelings.

Comment: Well, Area 51 could mix it up *a little*.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that our benevolent overlords wait until a site reached a very high level of traffic to enable the real advertisments. I'm not really worried that we don't carry ads yet. It seems that we are regarded as potential revenue, but for now the SE team considers the ads to be worse than the possible financial gain from them.

If we take Facebook and similar sites into account, it seems that many investors value a userbase quite highly, even if they don't pay much at the moment. The SE team probably has a good idea what our site is worth at the moment, but they want to let it grow a bit until they start making money from ads. As long as they don't worry I also wouldn't worry about it.